# Two arrays in for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

How can I use a for loop asking for student[0]'s grade, [1]'s etc? As of now, my for loop is pointless.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //declare grade and student array
    int[] grades = new int[5];
    String[] students = { "Bill", "Tom", "Mark", "Nic", "Miguel"};

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    for(int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        grades[i] = i + 1;

        //user input of student's grade
        System.out.print("Enter grade for " + students[0] + ": ");
        grades[0] = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter grade for " + students[1] + ": ");
        grades[1] = sc.nextInt();
    }
}
```

There must be a better way than hardcoding each student and grade array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take the input and assign it in the loop itself.

```
for(int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) 
{
    System.out.print("Enter grade for " + students[i] + ": ");
    grades[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

That's all. You do not need to repeat code as that is what the loop will do by accessing each element with the index `i`.

However, I am not sure what the line `grades[i] = i + 1;` accomplishes in your code, since you anyways overwrite that value with the one you get as input.

Answer (score 0):

If i am interpreting your question correct, what you want to do is accept grade values from user using for loop? My answer is as below, I have also printed grades which are accepted.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //declare grade and student array
    int[] grades = new int[5];
    String[] students = { "Bill", "Tom", "Mark", "Nic", "Miguel"};

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("please enter the grades of students");
    for(int i=0; i<students.length; i++){
       grades[i]= sc.nextInt();
    }

    for(int i=0; i<grades.length; i++){
        System.out.println(grades[i]);
    }

}
```